# Removing small areas only if no adjoining boundary

Tags: grass-gis

I'm generalizing some lat/lon data in grass64 and as a precursor to the generalization, I am removing small areas from the data using 'v.clean'.  The following command is working well:

```
$ v.clean input=foo output=foo_rmarea_100km tool=rmarea thresh=100000000 type=area --overwrite
```

However, the one problem I have is that it is removing a small area that has a shared border with the rest of the larger data set.

Is it possible to specify that only areas which DO NOT have a shared border with another area AND which are smaller than the defined threshhold be removed?

Answer (score 3):

I would first select the features from foo that have a shared border with the [v.select](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.select.html) tool and save them in foo_shared (using the *touches* or *overlaps* operator depending on the data).
Then I would clean the features from foo as you have done above with v.clean and save them in foo_clean.

Finally merging the two data sets from foo_shared and foo_clean with [r.patch](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.patch.html) should give you what you need.